# Show that $G$ contains a cycle of length at least $\sqrt k$.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph containing a cycle $C$, and assume that $G$ contains a path of length at least $k$ between two vertices of $C$. Show that G contains a cycle of length at least $\sqrt k$. Is this the best possible?

Comment: Check out http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~mubayi/591/Spring2010/hw1sol.pdf

Comment: Duplicate question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424107/maximum-cycle-in-a-graph-with-a-path-of-length-k

Answer (score 5):

Let $v_1,\dots,v_t$ be the common points on the path and the cycle.  If $t\geq \sqrt{k}$, then $C$ has at least $\sqrt{k}$ vertices then the proof is complete.  In the other case, for some $i$, there is a part of the path between $v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$ that contains at least $\sqrt{k}$ edges.  Now if you take the part of the path together with a path between $v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$ along the cycle, then you will get a cycle of length at least $\sqrt{k}$ as desired.